# I need help makeing a class named Automotive that holds value for vin make model color and make methods for them

Tags: class, methods, field

start
  Declarations
   Class Automobile
  string vin
  string make
  string model
  string color
input
output
stop

```
string vin = 12ABCD3456EFGH789
string make = "Acura"
string model = "Legand"
string color = "Throw up Brown"
string automobile = (string vin string make string model string color)
```

input Automobile(),

output automobile(),

output